# How Apache AirFlow achieves scalability?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, airflow

I see that, many operators in Airflow store the data locally, before uploading it to target system. This means worker node is doing considerable amount of work, in case the data is huge.

Airbnb (company who open sourced Airflow) says back in 2015 they had only 6 nodes in Airflow cluster serving 5000 jobs.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main purpose of the Apache Airflow is task scheduling and monitoring. It is not designed as a general data processing engine. Think rather as a replacement for Oozie than Apache Spark or Apache Hive.

While Airflow can scale it workers (with Mesos, RabbitMQ / Celery) the heavy lifting is still performed by the analytical systems. So for example Airflow can manage you Spark jobs and Druid queries, handle alters and such.